I have different structure of file in my angular project
I've tried to create a new project several times but I always get a structure containing files like app.route.ts and app.config.ts.
I'm expecting a structure containing files like app.routing.module.ts and app.module.ts.
Why am I not getting the structure I'm expecting when creating a new project?


What is the problem? Everything which has previously done in app.routing.module.ts can now be done in app.route.ts, and everything which has been done in  app.module.ts can now be done in app.config.ts. Also you can still create a new application with modules by running ng new --no-standalone.

The structure you're describing (with app.route.ts and app.config.ts) is the new default structure since standalone components became the default.
If you want to generate a project using modules instead, you can use the following command:
ng new project_name --standalone=false

